How to add a non-property to a bean class?
I have class with lots of fields, each with a getter and setter. We now need to add logging to some of these methods so I added the new logger-field:
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
    
    @JsonProperty("initialSize")
    private String initialSize;
    @JsonProperty("logAbandoned")
    private String logAbandoned;
    @JsonProperty("maxActive")
    private String maxActive;
    ...

This compiles just fine, but at run time I get an exception:

Invalid property 'logger' of bean class [com.example.Foo]: Bean
property 'logger' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the
setter?

Is there a way to mark the new field -- the logger -- as an exemption? I tried annotating it with @JsonIgnore, but that didn't help.

"but at run time I get an exception" : what code causes this?  You are going to need to provide a stack trace for someone to help you.

Thanks to @AndrewL for the hint. The problem was with our own code elsewhere, which was attempting to copy properties between different objects of this class. I added a check to skip static fields and that fixed it.
    public T overwriteCommonProperties(T target, T in) {
        if (in == null || target == null ||
            target.getClass() != in.getClass()) return null;
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(in);
        final BeanWrapper trg = new BeanWrapperImpl(target);
        for (final Field property : target.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(property.getModifiers()))
                continue;
            Object providedObject = src.getPropertyValue(property.getName());
            Object targetObject   = trg.getPropertyValue(property.getName());
            if (providedObject != null && null == targetObject &&
                !(providedObject instanceof Collection<?>)) {
                trg.setPropertyValue(
                    property.getName(),
                    providedObject);
            }
        }
        return target;
    }

